# python requests vs bash curl for session cookies

Tags: python, bash, curl, cookies, python-requests

I have a bash script that logs in to a website and fetches the json data from a URL and does other stuffs after that. I am trying to re-write the script using python but I am stuck at the log in part itself.

Below is a function from the bash script that I wrote, to login to the site and fetch the status

```
get_status()  {
curl -s ''"$url"'/target/app1/login' -c cookiejar
curl -s ''"$url"'/target/app1/login' -X POST -c cookiejar --data 'username='"$username"'&password='"$password"''
cookie=$(grep JSESSIONID cookiejar | awk '{print $6"="$7}')
status=$(curl -s ''"$url"'/target/app1/status' -H 'Cookie: '"$cookie"'' 
}
```

- The first curl gets a sample cookie to post to the login page in the
  second curl
- The second curl logs in using the username and password
  provided
- The third curl fetches the actual data using the
  'JSESSIONID' cookie

I am trying to do the same using requests in python as below

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get(url + "/target/app1/login")
print(session.cookies)
response = session.post(url + "/target/app1/login", data=data)
print(response.cookies)
```

In the above code the data variable holds the username and password string.

When I print the *response.cookies* I do not get the JSESSIONID cookie that I can use to authenticate future reqests to fetch data.

**Note**: When I print the response it returns 200

I am new to python, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having same issue hope this would help.

I was able to get this working with the below code.

```
session = requests.session()
session.get(url + "/target/app1/login")
login = session.post(url + "/target/app1/login", data)
data = session.get(url)
```